# Show the amount of posts in a tag in a specific category has

Tags: categories, tags, count

I am creating a page template in Wordpress that displays multiple tags that are in a particular category. I have this working, but now I want to have the number of posts within each tag that is displayed as well like if I had a tag called apples with 5 posts it would look like this:

```
Apples(5)
```

As of now it just shows `Apples`

Here is my code I want to modify:

```php
    <?php
      if (is_category()){
           $cat = get_query_var('cat');
           $yourcat = get_category ($cat);
       }
       $tag_IDs = array();
           query_posts('category_name=health');
                   if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                       $posttags = get_the_tags();
                           if ($posttags):
                           foreach($posttags as $tag) {
                               if (!in_array($tag->term_id , $tag_IDs)):
                                   $tag_IDs[] = $tag->term_id;
                                   $tag_names[$tag->term_id] = $tag->name;
                                   endif;
                       }
                       endif;
                       endwhile; endif;
                   wp_reset_query();
       
               echo "<ul>";
               foreach($tag_IDs as $tag_ID){
               echo '<a href="'.get_tag_link($tag_ID).'">'.$tag_names[$tag_ID].'</a>';
               }
           echo "</ul>";
       ?>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I see you've re-posted this question several times and then deleted it and reposted it. You shouldn't do that, you'll get flagged by the automated system for suspicious behaviour. It'll also put off people posting answers. **Stop it. If nobody answers your question, edit it to make it more attractive, don't spam the site**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code I rewrote that solved my problem. It loops through a category and shows how many articles all the tags inside the category has.

```
<?php
                            $custom_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=-1&category_name=health' );
                            if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) :
                                $all_tags = array();
                                while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : $custom_query->the_post();
                                    $posttags = get_the_tags();
                                    if ( $posttags ) {
                                        foreach($posttags as $tag) {
                                          $all_tags[$tag->term_id]['id'] = $tag->term_id;
                                          $all_tags[$tag->term_id]['name'] = $tag->name;
                                          $all_tags[$tag->term_id]['count']++;
                                        }
                                    }
                                endwhile;
                            endif;
    
                            $tags_arr = array_unique( $all_tags );
                            $tags_str = implode( ",", $tags_arr );
    
                            $args = array(
                                'smallest'  => 12,
                                'largest'   => 12,
                                'unit'      => 'px',
                                'number'    => 0,
                                'format'    => 'list',
                                'include'   => $tags_str
                            );
                            foreach ( $all_tags as $tag_ID => $tag ) {
                                echo '<a href="'.get_tag_link($tag_ID).'">' . $tag['name'] . '</a> ('; echo $tag['count'] . ')<br>';
                            }
                            wp_reset_query()
                         ?>
```

Comment: How does this fix the issue? It's just a code block with no explanation :(

Answer (score 1):

```
function wp_get_postcount($id)
{
    $contador = 0;
    $taxonomia = 'categoria';
    $args = array(
        'child_of' => $id,
    );
    $tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomia,$args);
    foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term){
        $contador +=$tax_term->contador;
    }
    return $contador;
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your answer to explain how this answers the OP's question?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get this is because you're using `query_posts` and looping over posts, not terms/categories.

So while you want this:

```
terms = child terms of health
for each term in terms
    print the term name
    print the number of posts in that term
```

What the code actually does is this:

```
posts = all posts that have the category health
for each posts
    print a list of tags this post has
```

`query_posts`, aside from being a function you should never use, fetches posts, not terms/categories. It does not make sense to fetch posts here.

So instead we need to do this:

```
healthterm = the health term
terms = child terms of health term
for each term in terms
    print the name
    print the post count
```

So first we get the health term:

```php
$parent = get_term_by( 'slug', 'health', 'category' );
```

Then get its children with something similar to this:

```php
$terms = get_terms( 'category', [
    'parent' => $parent->term_id
] );
```

And finally, loop over the terms and print their names/counts

```php
if ( !is_wp_error( $terms ) && !empty( $terms ) ) {
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        // ...
        echo $term->name . ' ' .$term->count;
    }
}
```

These are the missing building blocks you need to achieve your goal.

Comment: This did not work. It just spit out how many posts I have in each category.

Comment: But that's the title of your question, this answer gets the health tag and prints out the post count of its child terms. If that's not what you wanted then you need to update your question to ask what you wanted. Unless you're looking for a copy paste solution that requires no understanding, in which case I cannot provide that.

Comment: been studying up and using your example. I understand what you are doing in terms of logic and syntax, however nothing is rendered. I've changed the 1st and 2nd parameters get_term_by to id or slug instead of name. Is there something I'm missing? Here is what I have: <?php
       $parent = get_term_by('slug', 'health', 'category');
       $terms = get_terms('category', [
        'parent' => $parent->term_id
       ]);
       if(!is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms)) {
        foreach($terms as $term) {
         echo $term->name. ' ' .$term->count;
        }
       }
       ?>

Comment: that looks good, I can only assume that either `get_terms` returned an error object or an empty array, or, that `get_term_by` failed. An `else` case on the if statement will help diagnose the first case, but really you need to inspect the variables and double check they contain what you think they contain. Why guess if `$terms` is an error object, or empty when you can look and see for yourself? Likewise with `$parent`

Comment: All trouble shooting points to empty, do I need to do some sort of registration of the terms aka get_terms_by?

Comment: so is it empty because `$parent` is bad? Or is `$parent` good? If `get_term_by` failed you need to know, look at the contents of that variable, if it's a term object then we're good, if it's not then the function wasn't given the right values

Comment: $parent is bad because get_term_by('name, 'Health', 'category'); or any get_term_by is not rendering any data, that's why I ask if there is some sort of registration or init I'm missing.

Comment: no, you just need the right parameters, clearly there is no category with the name `Health`, keep in mind it has to be exact, and slugs are preferable. Have you confirmed by looking at the term that it is indeed `health`? Not `health-2`? Or `health `?

Comment: I tried to reproduce this locally, `$t = get_term_by( 'slug', 'health', 'category' );` worked fine for me. I recommend using the slug rather than the name. Double check and confirm `health` is actually the slug, and do not assume. There is no such thing as _it should be xyz_, check.

Comment: I've checked to see if the cats exist, if there are posts in the cats, tried different cats and they are all empty. One thing I noticed is that "health" is child of a parent category but I tried parent and still does't work. Does this need to be inside of the loop or something or I can call this from anywhere?

Comment: Rather than trying different values to see if they work though, have you inspected the term itself via either the database or WP Admin to see what its slug is? The parent term of the `health` term is irrelevant, all that matters is that you used the correct slug, if it isn't working then you did not use the correct slug. Note I am not referring to the human readable display name, but the internal name/slug used in the URL. Also, include in your question a screenshot showing the term in WP Admin

Comment: I'm using the correct slug and name according to wp-admin and database just added 2 screenshots thanks.

Comment: and you're sure this is a category? Not a tag? Not even `get_term_by( 'ID', 16, 'category' )`? If your term is a category, and it has the slug `health`, then `get_term_by( 'slug', 'health', 'category' )` is how you get it, I have confirmed this myself locally. How are you verifying that the term failed to be retrieved? Are you just modifying the `get_term_by` call and hoping to see a list of terms with counts?

Comment: yes i'm sure. i have tried all of those and I do a check with an else statement if array empty and it echos 'empty'. Yes have three instances of the code per category. and change the name per cat. Here is most up to date.  <?php
      $parent = get_term_by( 'slug', 'health', 'category' );
      $terms = get_terms('category', [ 'parent' => $parent->term_id ]);
      if(!is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms)) {
       foreach($terms as $term) { echo $term->name. ' ' .$term->count;
       }
      } ?>